# Is there any API for LinkedIn and Plaxo like facebook API?

Tags: asp.net

I need to access linkedin and plaxo social networks in my application. If I need to use this, I would lke to have the API for access linkedin and plaxo like Facebook API.

Is there any API for linkedIn and Plaxo?

Thanks
R.Eswaran.

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedIn API](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/linkedin) / [Plaxo API](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/plaxo)

Answer (score 1):

You will find everything about [LinkedIn API here](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis). The plaxo's api can be found by clicking [here](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/plaxo)

Answer (score 0):

I think LinkedIn and Plaxo use google's open social API